# problem with RX and web service collection loading wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, service, system.reactive

I'm beginner with C# and wp7 platform and I have some problem with good idea to get request from web service.

I made webservice in PHP (nusoap - WSDL) and everything is working fine in "normal" using.
Now I have ObservableCollection saved in IsolatedStorage with I load when Page is open (List of watched stacks exchange). Then I want to refresh data for every item from web service.

I don't know whether this is a good idea.

Code:

```
private GPWWebservicePortTypeClient client = new GPWWebservicePortTypeClient();
private ObservableCollection<WebServiceClass.ItemGetValues> StoredStock = 
                      new ObservableCollection<WebServiceClass.ItemGetValues>();     
public const string _fileName = "listaObserwowanych.xml";
public Page()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   DataContext = App.ViewModel;

   this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page_Loaded);

   client.GetLastValueCompleted +=
            new EventHandler<GetLastValueCompletedEventArgs>(client_GetLastValueCompleted);

   foreach (var itemGetValuese in App.ViewModel.Items)
   {
      client.GetLastValueAsync(itemGetValuese.name);
   }

   var o = 
       Observable.FromEvent<GetLastValueCompletedEventArgs(client,"GetLastValueCompleted")
                                                           .Subscribe(setList);
}

void client_GetLastValueCompleted(object sender, GetLastValueCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(e.Error));
    }
    else
    {
        ObservableCollection<WebServiceClass.ItemGetValues> ListValues = 
          (ObservableCollection<WebServiceClass.ItemGetValues>)                                                                      
           JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(e.Result, 
           typeof(ObservableCollection<WebServiceClass.ItemGetValues>));
        StoredStock.Add(ListValues[0]);
    }
}

private void setList(IEvent<GetLastValueCompletedEventArgs> ex)
{
    List.ItemsSource = StoredStock;
}


void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.ViewModel.LoadData();
    List.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.Items;
}
```

Like u see I use RX to call method client_GetLastValueCompleted add store result to auxiliary variable (StoredStock). Then refresh List in setList method, but that method is client_GetLastValueCompleted what is not soo good idea, becouse I need to run that method only when all of runned GetLastValueAsync in foreach is completed.
Second problem: becouse of async web service method StoredStock sometime have different order than App.ViewModel.Items .

Any good idea how to do that in right way?
Best regards,

Lukas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really mixing up a number of ways to call web services and Rx. You really need to decide on a single way and stick to it.

If you're going to use Rx, then you'll have something like this:

```
public Page()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = App.ViewModel;

    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page_Loaded);
}

void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.ViewModel.LoadData();

    var storedStock =
        new ObservableCollection<WebServiceClass.ItemGetValues>();  

    List.ItemsSource = storedStock;

    var values =
        Observable.Using<WebServiceClass.ItemGetValues, GPWWebservicePortTypeClient>
            (() => new GPWWebservicePortTypeClient(), ws =>
            {
                var clientGetLastValue = Observable
                    .FromAsyncPattern<string, GetLastValueResponse>
                    (ws.BeginGetLastValue, ws.EndGetLastValue);

                Func<string, WebServiceClass.ItemGetValues> deserializeFirst = r =>
                    ((List<WebServiceClass.ItemGetValues>)JsonConvert
                    .DeserializeObject(r,
                        typeof(List<WebServiceClass.ItemGetValues>)))
                    .First();

                return
                    from item in App.ViewModel.Items
                    from e in clientGetLastValue(item)
                    select deserializeFirst(e.Result);
            });

    values.Subscribe(storedStock.Add);
}
```

You'll have to get the right method call names for your web service client, but the code should roughly be right. Let me know how you go.

---

I corrected the code above. Should have returned the query inside the `Using` call rather than assign it to `values`.

---

I corrected the call to `FromAsyncPattern` to use the correct method names and return type from the actual web service reference class sent via email.

It should look like this:

```
Observable.FromAsyncPattern<string, GetLastValueResponse>
    (ws.BeginGetLastValue, ws.EndGetLastValue);
```

Comment: Big thanks for help, but could you explain what you mean with `ws.GetLastValueResult` my web service client don't have that method -> `private GPWWebservicePortTypeClient client = new GPWWebservicePortTypeClient();` ?

Comment: `void client_GetLastValueCompleted(object sender, GetLastValueCompletedEventArgs e)` I'm try to use that method - posted in question but vs is telling that `Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type System.Func<WP7GPW.GPWwebService.GPWWebservicePortTypeClient,System.IObservable<WP7GPW.WebServiceClass.ItemGetValues>`

Comment: @Enigmativity could you help with explain me more that?

Comment: @sliwinski - I've correct the sample code - I wasn't returning the query at the end of the `Using` call. As far as your method calls in your `GPWWebservicePortTypeClient` class you should note that I said you'd need to get the method names right. You should replace `GetLastValueResult` with the `EndInvoke` method call from your web service. And since you have the ability to call the service async, Rx will handle the return value for you when you use the `FromAsyncPattern` method so there is no need to use `GetLastValueCompleted` event handler.

Comment: @Enigmativity I think I know what you mean with EndInvoke method, but I can't find one in my PortTypeClient class generated by visual studio when I added service reference. Can I make it by myself like action or sth? If you want I can put project into net and you will see with what exacly I have problem.

Comment: @sliwinski - send me an email to `code` at my user name dot com.

Comment: @sliwinski - thanks for the code. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Enigmativity `Observable.FromAsyncPattern<string, GetLastValueResponse> (ws.BeginGetLastValue, ws.EndGetLastValue);` are you sure? I published BeginGetLastValue and EndGetLastValue methods from References web service but EndGetLastValue result type is string. Soo I changed it to `Observable.FromAsyncPattern<string, string>(ws.BeginGetLastValue, ws.EndGetLastValue);` but I have problem with types with `from e in clientGetLastValue(item)` it should be `clientGetLastValue(item.skrot)` - argument of webservice call with GetLastValue method is string

Comment: @sliwinski - I only looked at your code in notepad - I haven't got my environment set up to load the code in VS. I thought I got the right methods and return types, but you should be able to check it and make changes as needed. It shouldn't be too hard for you to get it working. Let me know what the final code looked like.

Comment: With your code I have problem with null pointer exception with func deserializeFirst. Look at my first edited post. I make the same code in antoher style and this works but when i debugging I don't know why but I have the same error null pointer exception with func deserializeFirst. I send you email with project - should work (web service is online)

Comment: @sliwinski - It's bad to edit your question so much. If you have follow up question you should post a new question. By changing the question so much people can't use your question and my answer to learn from. I've also provided a lot of help here for you and haven't got an upvote or an accepted answer, but what's worse, by changing your question you invalidate my answer and help. Please change it back, tick my answer (if you think I've solved it), and post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a beginner with C#, try to avoid RX for the time being. It is a cool technology, but if you use it without clear understanding of what is going on, it will bring more problems than solve.

Use a simple event, and when each async item arrives, locate and update the correspondent one in the stored list.